# Fitting Generalized Gaussian on Histogram python

Tags: python, scipy, histogram

I have a histogram of data, and I want to fit the generalized gaussian to this histogram.

As I have found out, I should use `scipy.stats.gennorm`. I use the following code but it seems like the distribution is not drawn based on the data, because it is the same for different histograms.
Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
def fit_generalized_gaussian(arr, axes):
        x = np.linspace(min(arr), max(arr), 100)
        axes.plot(x, gennorm.pdf(x, beta=0.45), color='red')

counter = 0
columns = 3
rows = 4
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 50))
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(rows, columns, squeeze=False)
for i, ax_row in enumerate(ax_array):
    for j, axes in enumerate(ax_row):
        axes.set_ylim([0, 0.05])
        fit_generalized_guassian(N_list[counter].ravel(), axes)
        axes.hist(N_list[counter].ravel(), 21, [-52.5, 52.5], density=True, color='blue')
        counter += 1
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

`N_list` is a list of images.
[image]

Comment: how is your data like - could you show a graph or put the code to reproduce your data graph. and could you explain or show what you get right now? 
x contains only 1 of the axis? if so then where is the data exactly?

Comment: @Orb Thank you for your time. The question has been edited.

Comment: Firstly, your `fit_generalized_gaussian` doesn't do a fit, it just draws the same curve each time (with the same `beta` parameter). Secondly, your data looks very inappropriate for a generalized gaussian which has one central peak.  Maybe you want to fit a [Gaussian kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)? Also note that seaborn has a specialized function [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) to create a grid of histograms together with kde plots.